# How to get failed token in FCM using php

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging, symfony-2.3

I use the **`fmcSendToServerAction`** function to send data to Firebase for sending push notifications to users, and I receive a response from FCM as follows: **`{"multicast_id":3518989135591430380,"success":1,"failure":2,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"48ccfe8f-b449-491a-b912-fe9cc86ab98e"}]}`**. How can I retrieve the failure tokens to update the active status in the database? Of course, the tokens generated when users agree to receive notifications have been saved in the database by me (see image).

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/fcm/send", name="fmc_send_to_server")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template(engine="php")
 */
public function fmcSendToServerAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $fcmTokens = $em->getRepository('VlanceBaseBundle:FcmToken')->findAll();
    $registrationIds = array_map(function ($ft) {
        return $ft->getToken();
    }, $fcmTokens);

    $fcmMessages = $em->getRepository('VlanceBaseBundle:FcmNotifyPush')->getFcmNotifyPush();

    $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    $server_key = "SERVER_MY_KEY";

    if (count($fcmMessages) <= 0) {
        return new Response('No notifications to send to users', 200);
    }

    foreach ($fcmMessages as $message) {
        $messageData = [
            'data' => [
                'title' => $message->getTitle(),
                'body' => $message->getDiscription(),
                'click_action' => $message->getUrl()
            ],
            'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
        ];

        $options = [
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                "Authorization: Bearer " . $server_key,
                "Content-Type: application/json",
            ],
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($messageData),
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // Capture the response
        ];

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // Get HTTP response code
        curl_close($curl);
    }
    return new Response('All notifications have been sent to users', 200);
}
```

Database: In which tokens with IDs 37 and 38 are failures.

[image]

How can I retrieve the failure tokens to update the active status in the database?

Comment: `"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"48ccfe8f-b449-491a-b912-fe9cc86ab98e"}]` - you should be able to relate this part directly to the three tokens you sent, no? First two failed, and for the third one you got a message_id back, so that one succeeded.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll need to do some additional processing to save information with the error tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CBroe commented, the three items in the `results` array of the respond correspond to the three tokens that you sent. So sending to the first two tokens failed (because the token is not known in this project and should probably be removed from your token database), and the third token succeeded.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll need to do some additional processing to save information with the error tokens.